# Are Google Play in-app purchases still valid if the app or the product is removed?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, app-store, in-app-billing

Some Android apps published on Google Play ask users to pay for something.
In the developer console of those apps there is some digital products that the user can buy.
What happens to the real products the users buy if the app is removed or the product is removed?
I mean: are the user buying something that depends on the product that's in the developer console or Google clones it for each purchase so purchases are still valid even if the app or the product is removed?