# Disable one in-app purchase as of a certain date

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

I have an Android app that has several features available as in-app purchases. We have published the app on both Google Play and the Amazon App Store. We need to stop offering one of the features as of a certain date. However, customers who have already purchased the feature should be able to use it past that date, even if they install the app on a new device. They should also still be able to purchase other features.

I was thinking that we could simply update our app so that the UI offered no option for purchasing the feature in question. However, that would not prevent a user with an older version of the app from purchasing the feature. So it seems like in addition to removing the feature purchase logic from the app (but not the feature itself), we need to do something to turn off the purchase at the store end. But whatever that something is, it must still allow the app to check whether the user had previously purchased the feature.

I've been unable to figure out from the Google Play or Amazon App Store documentation how to set this up. My understanding, from what I've read, is that removing the item (from either store) will cause checks for previous purchases to fail. Is it possible to do what I've described? We need solutions for both stores.

P.S. I did find one related question on SO: [Are Google Play in-app purchases still valid if the app or the product is removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33983295/535871) However, it has no answer and also is a little too narrowly framed. (I'm not assuming that the product has to be removed and I also need to know about the Amazon store.)

Comment: If my mind serves me it is possible to disable/deactivate specific product from Google Play console, unfortunately currently I have no access to a merchant account to test it out.

Comment: @azizbekian - Thanks for the comment. I'm aware that it's possible to do that on Google Play. Do  you know the effect of deactivating a product is on past purchases of that product? Would a call to `getPurchases()` still include that product in the result? Also, do you know if a similar functionality exists for the Amazon App Store?

Comment: `Would a call to getPurchases() still include that product in the result?` Querying for bought items will still return deactivated product in the list (again, if my mind serves me). Haven't ever worked with Amazon App Store, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

> I was thinking that we could simply update our app so that the UI
>   offered no option for purchasing the feature in question. However,
>   that would not prevent a user with an older version of the app from
>   purchasing the feature. So it seems like in addition to removing the
>   feature purchase logic from the app (but not the feature itself), we
>   need to do something to turn off the purchase at the store end.

For Amazon Appstore, you would need to contact [their support team](https://developer.amazon.com/support) to get the in-app item in question suppressed (it's not a self-service as of today). Once suppressed, that in-app item would no longer be purchasable. It would not affect existing users who purchased that item in the past.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've contacted Amazon support about this and we'll see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to in-app purchase I always opt for implementing everything in my own server. when a user buys something, I instantly consume it and notify my server. Then instead of querying Google or Amazon, I query my own server which gives me a lot of flexibility. If I face something like your problem I just add few lines of code!

Since you already published your app this may not work for you unless you willing to force users to update the app to the newer version. (Hoping you can do that!)

You mentioned that you don't know what happens if you deactivate the product and there is no documentation, well you can try it on a test project and see what happens! It shouldn't be that hard. If that doesn't work as you expect there is nothing you can do, your logic is in your app and it's already published so...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, running our own server is not an option. I was hoping to avoid experimenting to determine an answer, since that's not reliable. (Absent documentation, it's possible that what works today won't work tomorrow.)